# How to Get Data from Rotary Encoder at VERY High Speeds (>4500 RPM)

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

**Equipment:**

Arduino ATmega2560

Rotary Encoder: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B08RS6M32J/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Manual Curved Treadmill (what it looks like if you've never seen one before): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oil6cmUCog&ab_channel=ResolutionFitness

**Background:**

I have a manual treadmill and I want to use my Arduino to capture distance and speed data. To do this, my approach was to use a rotary encoder, attach it to a skateboard wheel (older picture is attached, I'm using a bigger wheel now and there's no photo for that right now) such that when I run on the treadmill, the wheel spins proportionately.

In the code below, whenever I run it, the counter variable would accumulate to about 2000 (pulses) every time the wheel makes a full rotation. The wheel diameter = 6cm, therefore, it's circumference = 18.8495559215 cm.

This means for every centimeter I travel, there are about 106 pulses. (2000 pulses/18.8495559215 cm = ~106 pulses/cm).

**Here's the code: (I got it from this website and only changed 2 lines of code because my sensor doesn't need to go in reverse; the treadmill only travels in one direction - https://electricdiylab.com/how-to-connect-optical-rotary-encoder-with-arduino/)**

```
volatile long temp, counter = 0; //This variable will increase or decrease depending on the rotation of encoder
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);

  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP); // internal pullup input pin 2 
  
  pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP); // internalเป็น pullup input pin 3
   //Setting up interrupt
  //A rising pulse from encodenren activated ai0(). AttachInterrupt 0 is DigitalPin nr 2 on moust Arduino.
  attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);
   
  //B rising pulse from encodenren activated ai1(). AttachInterrupt 1 is DigitalPin nr 3 on moust Arduino.
  attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);
  }
   
  void loop() {
  // Send the value of counter
  if( counter != temp && counter % 106 == 0 ){ // Only print something if the wheel travels in increments of 1 cm.
  Serial.println (counter);
  temp = counter;
  }
  }
   
  void ai0() {
  // ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 2 is going from LOW to HIGH
  // Check pin 3 to determine the direction
  if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
  counter++;
  }else{
  counter++; // The original code said counter-- but my treadmill only goes one direction and the this variable starts to decrease when I reach a certain speed (around 5 kmk/h or (3.1 mph) or so). After I changed it to counter++, this issue was resolved however, the arduino serial monitor kept freezing at high speeds.


  }
  }
   
  void ai1() {
  // ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 3 is going from LOW to HIGH
  // Check with pin 2 to determine the direction
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {
  counter++; //// The original code said counter-- but my treadmill only goes one direction and the this variable starts to decrease when I reach a certain speed (around 5 kmk/h or (3.1 mph) or so). After I changed it to counter++, this issue was resolved however, the arduino serial monitor kept freezing at high speeds.
  }else{
  counter++;
  }
  }
```

**The Problem**

*To get the speed is easy, it's just not in this code right now. Accomplished by using t1 and t2 variables and the Millis() function.

When I walk on the treadmill, I typically walk at about 4 or 5 km/h (3.1 mph). This works fine. However, the issue is I want to be able to sprint over 30 km/h (18.6 mph) and have the code be able to support up to 50 km/h (31 mph). Right now, I'm unable to run at speeds over 5 km/h without the serial monitor freezing periodically, or there being inaccurate data.

At these speeds, I would need the sensor to support the wheel moving at over 4500 RPM -> 75 RPS or (75 RPS x 2000 P/R = 150,000 Pulses/Second)

I have absolutely no idea why this issue is happening and how I should approach this to achieve my desired speeds.

Possible reasons why this is happening:

I'm not an expert at Arduino at all and am just starting to understand things like interrupts. I have my pins in 2 and 3. Should I leave this alone or change it?

If you click the Amazon link, you'll see that there is a 3rd Orange "Z" wire which I have absolutely no idea what it does. The few tutorials I could find only involve the two "A" and "B" wires. Maybe incorporating the "Z" wire would point me in the right direction?

My Rotary encoder sensor is using the Arduino's 5V. If you click on the Amazon link, you'd see that it actually supports up to 26V. Should I find an external power source that allows up to 26V and pair it with a relay? Not sure if the extra voltage will help me.

I'm not sure why by default, the sensor counted a full rotation for the wheel to be 2000 pulses. On Amazon, you'll see that it supports the following Pulses/Revolution:

Resolution (pulse/rotation) : 100, 200, 300, 360, 400, 500, 600, 1000, 1024, 1200, 2000, 2500, 3600, 5000 (optional)

How can I change my 2000 P/R to 5000 P/R for example? Would this help?

**Summary**

I want to use my Arduino and rotary sensor to collect speed and distance data from my manual treadmill. At slow speeds (up to 5 km/h), the code works fine, but at high speeds, the data is highly inaccurate, and the serial monitor freezes every few seconds. I want the Arduino to support speeds up to 50 km/h which is about 4500 RPM. If my solution with the rotary sensor is not feasible, I am 100% open to other ideas as I just want the speed and distance data. I'll purchase any new equipment that's necessary but ideally, I'd like to work with what I have right now.

Thank you for your help!
[image]

Comment: I would use a magnet sticked on the surface of the trackmill and place a magnetic sensor to detect the magnet when it pass-by, it would be much less demanding on arduino and arguably more accurate...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's basically an electro-mechanical question.

Comment: See my close reason above.   This is an electro-mechanical question.  I'd suggest a Hall sensor, maybe a few of them mounted inside the track, and getting rid of all rotating devices and possibly posting the hardware question on the Electronics Stack.

Answer (score 0):

Well I looked at the [datasheet](https://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/e6b2-c_ds_e_6_1_csm491.pdf?id=487) of your encoder and I was also very confused regarding the multiple values of resolution... what I suspect is that maybe there are different E6B2-CWZ6C models with differnt ppr's...

But what was useful was that I found out that your encoder is an incermental rotary encoder ([this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=005lyrHGeE8) explains better the inner workings of your type of encoder) what this means is that you have three wires A black, B white and Z the orange one.

As described on the video when your shaft completes 1 full rotation you will get N quantity of pulses from A and B, but depending on which pulse you get first would determines the rotation, according to the diagram below, if you first get a pulse from A it would mean that the rotation is CW but if you get B first it would then be CCW.

[image]

So for example lets say you start with a pulse_count=0 and start turning your shaft CW and you start counting the pulses on A, the count would go 0,1,2... and so on, but how would you know when to stop counting? that's when the Z orange cable comes in place, because it makes a pulse only after a whole rotation has been made so let's say you counted up to 200 and then you get a pulse from Z then you would know that you should restart your count back to the begining.

So to solve your problem and if you are only interested in the measured speed i would sugest to only measure how long does it take from one Z pulse to the next one, which would tell you how long it took for your encoder to complete one rotation, which could then be use to calculate the speed.
[image]

If we solve for rpms using this formula we get that RPM=(V*60)/(2pi*r) if V=50km/h=13.88 m/s and r=3cm=0.03m we get that at 50km/h we would get 4418.14 rpm or 4418/60= 73.63 revs per sec what means 73 pulses of Z every second.

What was maybe happening is that for example if A had a resolution of 2000 ppr would imply that for every second you were receiving 73*2000 = 146000 pulses every second and as you configured your baudrate for your serial communication at [Serial.begin](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/es/language/functions/communication/serial/begin/)(9600) you were only capable of reading at most 9600 pulses for each second which is way less than your 146000 pulses in A. However there are different baudrates you can set: 300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 38400, 57600, or 115200. Just be sure to select the same audrate when using the serial monitor.

Answer (score 0):

For extremely high speeds you have to use bit operators and port registers.

Try this code with the equivalent pins CLK and DT connected to A2 and A1 receptively.

```
// Rotary Encoder Inputs
#define CLK A2
#define DT A1

int counter = 0;
String currentDir ="";
unsigned char currentPairBit = 0b0; // 8 bits
unsigned char lastPairBit = 0b0; // 8 bits

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  DDRC = 0b00000000; // Set Analog(C) encoder pins as inputs
  
}

void loop() {

  while(true) { // while cycle is faster than loop!

    // reads the analog states!
    currentPairBit = PINC >> 1 & 0b11; // Gets A2(PC2) and A1(PC1) bits on C (analog input pins) (>> 1 = Jumps pin 0)
    
    if ((lastPairBit & 0b11) != currentPairBit) {
  
      lastPairBit = lastPairBit << 2 | currentPairBit;
      
      // Bit Pairs Cyclic Sequence:
      //  1.   2.   3.   4.   5.
      //  11 | 01 | 00 | 10 | 11 for CCW
      //  11 | 10 | 00 | 01 | 11 for CW
      if (lastPairBit == 0b01001011 || lastPairBit == 0b10000111) {
    
        if (lastPairBit == 0b01001011) {
          currentDir = "CCW";
          counter--;
        } else {
          currentDir = "CW";
          counter++;    
        }
        
        Serial.print("Direction: ");
        Serial.print(currentDir);
        Serial.print(" | Counter: ");
        Serial.println(counter);
      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then check the Serial Monitor to see how fast it is. Note that you should avoid the `delay()` function in your code or any other that interrupts the cycle by too much time. Consider using a second auxiliary Arduino for anything else than counting.

Resulting Serial Output:
[image]